# ¿Como hacer para que el programa me diga el sumatorio de 5 es 10 y no el sumatorio de 0 es 10

Tags: java

en el siguiente codigo que compila y ejecuta me sale que el numero a hacer la sumatoria es 0 pero la sumatoria al meterle el numero que sea si me la hace correctamente. Aquí el codigo:

```
import java.util.*;
class Args{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        //Atributos 
        int iNumero=0;
        int iSumatorio=0;
        int iCuenta= iNumero;
        System.out.println("Introduce un número para calcular su sumatoria");
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        iCuenta = teclado.nextInt();
            while (iCuenta != 0) {
                iSumatorio = iSumatorio + iCuenta;
                iCuenta--;
                iSumatorio--;

            }

                System.out.println("El sumatorio de " + iCuenta + " es " + iSumatorio);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver...en cada iteracion vas decrementando iCuenta en 1...con lo cual, al salir del bucle while, iCuenta vale 0 y es correcto que te diga "El sumatorio de 0 es X".
Lo que deberias hacer es tener otra variable, a la cual le asignas el valor original de iCuenta (leido del teclado) y la usas para poner el mensaje, asi:

```
import java.util.*;
class Args{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        //Atributos 
        int iNumero=0;
        int iSumatorio=0;
        int iCuenta= iNumero;
        System.out.println("Introduce un número para calcular su sumatoria");
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        iCuenta = teclado.nextInt();
        int iCuentaOrig = iCuenta;
            while (iCuenta != 0) {
                iSumatorio = iSumatorio + iCuenta;
                iCuenta--;
                iSumatorio--;

            }

                System.out.println("El sumatorio de " + iCuentaOrig + " es " + iSumatorio);
    }
}
```

Comment: Permitid-me insistir, en que el sumatorio de 5 es 15, no 10, ese "iSumatorio--" sobra.

Comment: Si, todo bien. Es correcto que la sumatoria no es 10 sino 15...pero no es lo central de la pregunta sino porque perdía el valor inicial de iCuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Veo algunos fallos.
Primero, el sumatorio de 5 es 15, no 10 como esperas. (5+4+3+2+1=15)
Segundo, dentro el `while`, después de hacer la suma (`iSumatorio=...`) decrementas  `iSumatorio`, cosa que no le veo sentido, y es por eso que da 10 y no 15 (al hacer 5 iteraciones, decrementa el resultado 5 veces, por eso da 10).
Tercero, si usas `Icuenta` para contar las iteriaciones, decrementando (`iCuenta--;`), al final del bucle evidentemente valdrá 0 (de hecho que valga 0 es la condición de salida del bucle) y por eso al mostrar la variable sale 0 y no 5.
Para finalizar has declarado una variable que no usas (`iNumero`).

Una posible solución:
Si no quieres modificar la variable donde guardas el numero a hacer el sumatorio, para usarlo después, usa otra para hacer de contador, por ejemplo, guarda en "`iNumero`" el numero introducido en el teclado, y usa `iCuenta` como contador.
Como el numero de iteraciones es fija, puede ser mas comprensible usar un bucle `for` y no un `while`.
Código de ejemplo:

```
import java.util.*;
class Args{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        //Atributos 
        int iNumero, iCuenta;
        int iSumatorio=0;

        System.out.println("Introduce un número para calcular su sumatoria");
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        iNumero= teclado.nextInt();

        for (iCuenta=1 ; iCuenta<=iNumero ; iCuenta++) {
            iSumatorio += iCuenta;
        }

        System.out.println("El sumatorio de " + iNumero+ " es " + iSumatorio);
    }
}
```